# Как вывести элемент списка Python

Tags: python

Всем добрый день. Подскажите, как можно ввести число и вывести из списка именно такое число элементов, которое я ввёл? Например:

```
a = ['раз', 'два', 'три', 'четыре', 'пять', 'шесть', 'семь', 'восемь', 'девять', 'десять']
n = int(input('число, сколько слов нужно вывести'))
```

Если я ввожу три, то должно вывести из списка первые три элемента, а именно: раз, два, три. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: `print(a[:int(n)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вашей задачи в `python` подойдет решение с помощью срезов. Вы можете почитать о них, например, [здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html).

Конструкция выглядит так

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# items[start:stop:step]
print(items[0:1])
# 1
print(items[0:5:2])
# 1 3 5
```

Возможен вариант, при котором одно из значений не указывается. Следующие записи попарно эквивалентны.

```
print(items[0:1])
print(items[:1])

print(items[2:5])
print(items[2:])

print(items[0:5:2])
print(items[::2])
```